# ManyToMany relation with symfony 3.4 (creating link between two tables with api )

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I am trying to create a link between two tables with a ManyToMany relation in symfony. I have a Post table with is basically a table to store all post from users (like Facebook post, with comments, likes, users etc) and I also have a tag table that stores all the different tags created by the users. The relation manytomany is to help me have a link between the post and it's tags.

It works fine for the mentioned users which works exactly the same way as the tags. (The mentioned users are like the tags but you can only tag people). The actual tags are meant to give the users the possibility to tag events and companies to the post. They will then be able to search threw all existing tags, a bit like Instagram.

Here is my Tag Entity:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="tag_id_uindex", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $libelle
     */
    public function setLibelle($libelle)
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $posts
     */
    public function setPosts($posts)
    {
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }

}
```

Here is my Post Entity:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="post_id_uindex", columns={"id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="post_post_type_id_fk", columns={"post_type_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="post_club_id_fk", columns={"club_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="post_user_id_fk", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $enabled = true;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    ///**
    // * @var string
    // *
    // * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
    // */
    //private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="attachment", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $attachment;

    /**
     * @var Club
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Club")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="club_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $club;

    /**
     * @var PostType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PostType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $postType;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Manager
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Manager")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manager_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_has_tag",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_has_user",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mentioned_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $mentionedUsers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostComment", mappedBy="post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostLike", mappedBy="post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $likes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->mentionedUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->likes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function getManager()
    {
        return $this->manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param Manager $manager
     */
    public function setManager($manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $enabled
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getCreateDate()
    {
        return $this->createDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime $createDate
     */
    public function setCreateDate($createDate)
    {
        $this->createDate = $createDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return Club
     */
    public function getClub()
    {
        return $this->club;
    }

    /**
     * @param Club $club
     */
    public function setClub($club)
    {
        $this->club = $club;
    }

    /**
     * @return PostType
     */
    public function getPostType()
    {
        return $this->postType;
    }

    /**
     * @param PostType $postType
     */
    public function setPostType($postType)
    {
        $this->postType = $postType;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $tags
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getMentionedUsers()
    {
        return $this->mentionedUsers;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $mentionedUsers
     */
    public function setMentionedUsers($mentionedUsers)
    {
        $this->mentionedUsers = $mentionedUsers;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttachment()
    {
        return $this->attachment;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $attachment
     */
    public function setAttachment($attachment)
    {
        $this->attachment = $attachment;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $comments
     */
    public function setComments($comments)
    {
        $this->comments = $comments;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLikes()
    {
        return $this->likes;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $likes
     */
    public function setLikes($likes)
    {
        $this->likes = $likes;
    }


}
```

Here is also my User Entity that works fine with the Post Entity:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_email_uindex", columns={"email"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_id_uindex", columns={"id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_company_id_fk", columns={"company_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="username already taken")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var Company
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="mentionedUsers")
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="avatar", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $avatar;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone_number", type="integer")
     */
    private $phone_number;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="linkedin_url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $linkedin_url;

    private $current_club;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $firstName
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $lastName
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return Company
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * @param Company $company
     */
    public function setCompany($company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $posts
     */
    public function setPosts($posts)
    {
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $position
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAvatar()
    {
        return $this->avatar;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $avatar
     */
    public function setAvatar($avatar)
    {
        $this->avatar = $avatar;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phone_number;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $phone_number
     */
    public function setPhoneNumber($phone_number)
    {
        $this->phone_number = $phone_number;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkedinUrl()
    {
        return $this->linkedin_url;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $linkedin_url
     */
    public function setLinkedinUrl($linkedin_url)
    {
        $this->linkedin_url = $linkedin_url;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrentClub()
    {
        return $this->current_club;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $current_club
     */
    public function setCurrentClub($current_club)
    {
        $this->current_club = $current_club;
    }

}
```

Here is a snippet from my controllers that handle the relation between the Post and the tags when the post is created :

```php
 /**
     * @Rest\Post(
     *     path="posts",
     *     name="post_creation"
     * )
     * @Rest\RequestParam(
     *     name="content",
     *     description="content of post"
     * )
     * @Rest\RequestParam(
     *     name="postType",
     *     description="type of post: text, image, video or gallery"
     * )
     *
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"post_creation"})
     */
    public function postCreateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $text = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PostType::class)->find('1');
        $image = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PostType::class)->find('2');
        $video = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PostType::class)->find('3');
        //$gallery = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PostType::class)->find('4');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //$title = $request->request->get('title');
        $content = $request->request->get('content');
        $postType = $request->request->get('postType');

        if ($content == null) {
            return new JsonResponse('invalid post');
        }
        $post = new Post();
        $now = new DateTime('now');

        switch ($postType) {
            case text_type:
                $user = $this->getUser()->getUser();
                $post->setClub($user->getCurrentClub());
                $post->setPostType($text);
                $post->setCreateDate($now);
                $post->setContent($content);
                $post->setUser($user);
                $em->persist($post);
                $em->flush();
                $post_tags = json_decode($request->request->get('tags'), true);

                if ($post_tags != null) {
                    foreach ($post_tags as $post_tag) {
                        $tag = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Tag::class)->findOneBy(['libelle' => $post_tag]);
                        if ($tag == null) {
                            $new_tag = new Tag();
                            $new_tag->setLibelle($post_tag);
                            $em->persist($new_tag);
                            $em->flush();
                            $post->getTags()->add($new_tag);

                        } else {
                            $post->getTags()->add($tag);
                            $em->flush();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //handle mentioned users
                $mentioned_users_id = json_decode($request->request->get('mentioned_users_id'), true);
                if ($mentioned_users_id != null) {
                    foreach ($mentioned_users_id as $mentioned_user_id) {
                        $mentioned_user_input = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $mentioned_user_id]);
                        if ($mentioned_user_input != null) {
                            $post->getMentionedUsers()->add($mentioned_user_input);
                        }
                    }
                }

                $em->flush();
                return $post;
                break;

            case image_type:
                $filePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'UploadedFile');
                $file = fopen($filePath, "w");
                stream_filter_append($file, 'convert.base64-decode');
                fwrite($file, $request->request->get('attachment'));
                $meta_data = stream_get_meta_data($file);
                $path = $meta_data['uri'];
                fclose($file);
                $fileName = $this->getUser()->getId() . "_" . uniqid() . '.' . $request->request->get("ext");
                $new_path = $this->getParameter('post_directory') . $fileName;
                rename($path, $new_path);
                $user = $this->getUser()->getUser();
                $post->setClub($user->getCurrentClub());
                $post->setPostType($image);
                $post->setCreateDate($now);
                $post->setContent($content);
                $post->setUser($user);
                $post->setAttachment($fileName);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->flush();
                return $post;

            case video_type:
                $video_file = $request->request->get('attachment');
                $user = $this->getUser()->getUser();
                $post->setClub($user->getCurrentClub());
                $post->setPostType($video);
                $post->setCreateDate($now);
                $post->setContent($content);
                $post->setUser($user);
                $post->setAttachment($video_file);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->flush();
                return $post;

            //case gallery_type:
            //    $gallery_file_array = [];
            //    $gallery_array = explode(',', $request->request->get('attachment'));
            //    foreach ($gallery_array as $image) {
            //        if ($image) {
            //            $filePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'UploadedFile');
            //            $file = fopen($filePath, "w");
            //            stream_filter_append($file, 'convert.base64-decode');
            //            fwrite($file, $image);
            //            $meta_data = stream_get_meta_data($file);
            //            $path = $meta_data['uri'];
            //            fclose($file);
            //            $fileName = $this->getUser()->getId() . "_" . uniqid() . '.' . $request->request->get("ext");
            //            $new_path = $this->getParameter('post_directory') . $fileName;
            //            rename($path, $new_path);
            //            $gallery_file_array[] = $fileName;
            //        }
            //    }
//
            //    if (count($gallery_file_array)) {
            //        $post->setAttachment(json_encode($gallery_file_array));
            //        $current_user = $this->getUser()->getUser();
            //        $post->setClub($this->getUser()->getManager()->getClub());
            //        $post->setPostType($gallery);
            //        $post->setCreateDate($now);
            //        $post->setTitle($title);
            //        $post->setContent($content);
            //        $post->setUser($current_user);
            //        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            //        $em->persist($post);
            //        $em->flush();
            //        return $post;
            //    }
            //    break;
            default:
                return new JsonResponse('post creation invalid');
        }
    }
```

I don't have any error messages. The tag table is created if the tag doesn't already exist. For the mentioned users, It all works fine. It's just the link that doesn't seem to be created and uploaded my post_has_tag table on my database.

Here is a screen of my post_has_tag class in phpmyadmin :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJNFy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tags are being saved because they are persisted individually on loop.

To save intermediate entities (relation tables) without calling `persist()` on intermediate table, you should use `cascade={"persist"}` on you manyToMany definition.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Will try your solution and keep you updated.

Comment: Hey again, tried your solution but no luck, still have the same problem. I need to persist them individually in loop because if the tags don't exist, i need to create them and then link them with my post. Thank you anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a method in Post entity to link tags to post :

```
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{ 
    if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }
}
```

And add Tag like that :

```
$post->addTag($new_tag);
```

Comment: Thanks again for your quick responses. Will try it now and keep you updated. However, I don't get what changes between your "$this->tags->add($tag)" and my "$post->getTags()->add($new_tag);". To me It's the same. I do it like so because I know all my tags exist since I already looped before this to check if they exist and if not, i create them. This doesn't really solve my issue here.

Comment: Estève means that instead of `$post->getTags()->add($new_tag);` you could create the method he has shown. maybe your are not persisting post neither tags after being added to post `$post->getTags()->add($new_tag);` you are persisting and flushing `$post` before assigning tags.

Comment: Hello, just tried your solution, still does't work. The fact of persisting the post before or after I assign the tags to it should not modify or interfere with how the database saves the link between my two tables.  Thank you anyways for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you can just set the Post when you create the new Tag like : `$new_tag->setLibelle($post_tag); $new_tag->addPost($post) `

Comment: I can't do that because Post is the owner and not tag. The tag is created if it doesn't already exists, and persisted in the database. The problem is that doctrine doesn't save/create the link in my post_has_tag table. I think it's a doctrine error.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  I finally managed to fix my bug. I basically regenerated all my entities and recreated my post_has_tag table (also recreating all the links) and it worked again. Haven't found the source of the bug yet. Will try and update this issue in the future if i find why this issue occured. Thanks again for your help!